# ElasticSearch 5.4.0 query (PHP)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

To connect to ElastickSearch, I use [basemkhirat/elasticsearch](https://packagist.org/packages/basemkhirat/elasticsearch). The following problem was formed: Using this method with this query("google.com") to search links in index

```
ES::type("links")->search("google.com")->get();
```

I'm found 56 links (for example), but if I used query "google"

```
ES::type("links")->search("google")->get();
```

I'm found nothing(0). What is my problem?

JSON Query, witch created through the search:

```
{
    "index":"links",
    "type":"link",
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query":"google.com"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "from":0,
    "size":10000
}
```

P.S: In [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) I'm watching the same things.

Comment: is search matching full stings? or using wild cards?

Comment: Precisely I do not know, but most likely this method is similar to the search line in Kibana Web interface

Comment: well its your job to find out hat the code your using does, not ours

Comment: Judging by the request it would be not like a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into the library you're using but it looks like doing a wild card query will work for you. It won't perform great if you have a lot of data, or if you overuse the wildcard.

Something like this might work for you - let me know how it goes.

```
ES::type("links")->search("google*")->get();
```

PS, if I were in your position, I would have looked into the library and tried to find out if they support Prefix queries. I'm assuming they must be - might want to spend couple of hours looking there.